# GPT2 vs. Llama2 have different Behavior with device_map="auto"

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers

TL;DR - paste the code in a file and try both models and llama will give an error

I have been working with two different language models, [gpt2-xl](https://huggingface.co/gpt2-xl) and [llama-2-7b-chat-hf](https://huggingface.co/meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf) via [torch](https://pytorch.org/) and [transformers](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/index). When I load gpt2-xl as a pretrained model, I can include or exclude `device_map="auto"` and it will still work. With Llama, however, it only works when device_map is excluded, and I'm curious why there's a difference in behavior between the two models. I'd love it if someone showed me how to fix this issue while still using llama-2-7b and spreading it out to all the GPUs rather than just one. I'm also curious as to why using device_map with gpt2-xl has such a different response than without.

I have a AMD Ryzen 3 1200 Quad-Core Processor, 32gb ram, six 3070tis with 8GiB memory each on Ubuntu Desktop 20.0.4

Here is the code (also steps to re-create environment for duplication are below)

```py
modelName = "meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf"
# modelName = "gpt2-xl"

import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig, set_seed

set_seed(0)

# load model in 4-bit
quantization_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
    load_in_4bit=True,
    bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.float16
)

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(modelName)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    modelName,
    quantization_config=quantization_config,
    device_map="auto",
)

input_text = "Hello my dog is cute and"
inputs = tokenizer(input_text, return_tensors="pt").to("cuda")

# enable FlashAttention
with torch.backends.cuda.sdp_kernel(enable_flash=True, enable_math=False, enable_mem_efficient=False):
    outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=50, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)

print(tokenizer.decode(outputs[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

gpt2-xl output with device_map="auto"

> Hello my dog is cute and! DrILE!!!!!! Comp!!!!!!!!!!Moreover!!!ula!! predictsNetMessage!NetMessage orchestraNetMessage!NetMessageabsorNetMessage龍�NetMessage* laure inferior businessmen adherentsorbit scripting Az Rat rankings warriors

gpt2-xl output without it

> Hello my dog is cute and I love her. I love her so much. I love her so much. I love her so much. I love her so much. I love her so much. I love her so much. I love her so much. I love her so

Llama-2-7b-chat-hf without it

> Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|██████████████| 2/2 [00:36<00:00, 18.26s/it]
>
> Hello my dog is cute and I want to show it off to the world. Unterscheidung von "Cute" und "Attractive" bezieht sich auf die Art und Weise, wie das Wort in verschiedenen Kontexten verwendet wird. Cute is a term used

Llama-2-7b-chat-hf with it

```
Loading checkpoint shards: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 2/2 [00:29<00:00, 14.96s/it]
/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py:726: UserWarning: Memory efficient kernel not used because: (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/transformers/cuda/sdp_utils.cpp:367.)
  attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(
/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py:726: UserWarning: Memory Efficient attention has been runtime disabled. (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/transformers/sdp_utils_cpp.h:437.)
  attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(
/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py:726: UserWarning: Flash attention kernel not used because: (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/transformers/cuda/sdp_utils.cpp:369.)
  attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(
/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py:726: UserWarning: Both fused kernels do not support non-null attn_mask. (Triggered internally at ../aten/src/ATen/native/transformers/sdp_utils_cpp.h:261.)
  attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flash.py", line 27, in <module>
    outputs = model.generate(**inputs, max_new_tokens=50, pad_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/utils/_contextlib.py", line 115, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1764, in generate
    return self.sample(
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 2861, in sample
    outputs = self(
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 1181, in forward
    outputs = self.model(
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 1068, in forward
    layer_outputs = decoder_layer(
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 796, in forward
    hidden_states, self_attn_weights, present_key_value = self.self_attn(
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1518, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1527, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/username/aiTests/.env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/models/llama/modeling_llama.py", line 726, in forward
    attn_output = torch.nn.functional.scaled_dot_product_attention(
RuntimeError: No available kernel.  Aborting execution.
```

Steps to recreate

```bash
# upon fresh install
# update, upgrade, update, and make sure you have python3.8 and pip
mkdir aiTest && cd aiTest
python3 -m venv .env && source .env/bin/activate
# rustup for cuda stuff
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh
# CUDA Toolkit 12.3
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64/cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-keyring_1.1-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install cuda-toolkit-12-3
# To install the open kernel module flavor:
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-kernel-open-545
sudo apt-get install -y cuda-drivers-545
# get ai stuff like
pip install torch transformers
nano flash.py #paste in my file
python flash.py
# I like this in another tab to check on GPUs
watch -n 1 nvidia-smi
```